# Are 'include' and 'define' also considered as keywords in C?

Tags: c, keyword

Since we use 'include' and 'define' only after # in C, that too at the start of the program; do we still consider them as keywords? Can we declare variables called include or define?

```
int include, define;
```

Is this wrong? The thing is, it shouldn't be wrong according to me. I tried this out and it does not give me any errors. However, my university conducted a quiz in which they said that these 2 declarations are wrong.

Comment: [Reserved Keywords in **C**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword).You did ask your university *why* this was wrong, right? If so, update your question with their response; if not, why not?

Comment: They are not keyword. And they only can do their preprocessing task when a hash(#) is given at the starting.

Comment: Is it the Mumbai University?

Comment: @Sourav Yes, and it does not give me any errors.

Comment: I did ask them, but they haven't responded clearly. They keep avoiding it.

Comment: You are just one of the usual complainees in that case. Some don't even get the hall tickets. :)

Answer (score 4):

No, they are *preprocessing directives* like `#line` or `#error`. They are not considered as keywords. You can have pretty much variables like `int line` or `int error`.

Comment: Exactly! Please see the edit. I will ask my university for a recheck.

Answer (score 1):

As per the `C11` specification, chapter §6.4.1, *keywords*, `include` and `define` does not appear in the reserved keywords list. So they are **not** keywords.

FWIW, the list of *keywords*, as it appears,

> *keyword: one of*
>
> ```
> auto ∗
> break
> case
> char
> const
> continue
> default
> do
> double
> else
> enum
> extern
> float
> for
> goto
> if
> inline
> int
> long
> register
> restrict
> return
> short
> signed
> sizeof
> static
> struct
> switch
> typedef
> union
> unsigned
> void
> volatile
> while
> _Alignas
> _Alignof
> _Atomic
> _Bool
> _Complex
> _Generic
> _Imaginary
> _Noreturn
> _Static_assert
> _Thread_local
> ```

Answer (score 0):

No they are not Keywords like int,char,if,while,etc but they are pre-processors which begin with hash symbol "#".These pre-processors are used for linking,defining,etc purposes
For more information u can refer,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Answer (score 0):

No Keywords but instead `include` and `define` are **C Preprocessor Directives**,

## Quote:

> the C preprocessor modifies a source file before handing it over to the compiler, allowing conditional compilation with >#ifdef, defining constants with #define, including header files with #include, and using builtin macros such as **FILE**. >This page lists the preprocessor directives, or commands to the preprocessor, that are available:

---

## FWIW:

There are another prepocessors...

[#define](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/define.html)

[#undef](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/undef.html)

[#if](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/if.html)

[#ifdef](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/ifdef.html)

[#ifndef](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/ifndef.html)

[#error](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/error.html)

[**FILE**](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/__FILE__.html)

[**LINE**](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/__LINE__.html)

[**DATE**](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/__DATE__.html)

[**TIME**](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/__TIME__.html)

[**TIMESTAMP**](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/__TIMESTAMP__.html)

[pragma](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/pragma.html)

[# macro operator](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/stringizing-operator.html)

[## macro operator](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/token-pasting-operator.html)

Comment: You should include the source of your quotes. Also, some directives are not ISO C.